# Using xpath to lookup value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this structure,

[image: XML structure]

Can I use xpath on this to first locate the id W01001 and then get the value for _ on the same level?

The xml is the result of a webservice and changes between different questions, input and type of result returned. The only thing we can rely on is the W01001, W01002 and so on so the xpath may only use that.

If this cant be done with xpath, what alternative solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really not entirely sure about what the elements in brackets mean or what you structure is, but assuming that the _ is an attribute (not sure if it can be), the node would be:

```
//*[@id='W01001']/@_
```

if it is shortcut for the element, it would be:

```
//*[@id='W01001']
```